# Order status not changed in open cart 2.0.2.0 (json error)

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Recently i am facing this problem. from starting it is working good.
Order Status not changed, not deleted and not edited.

looking for possible solutions on internet, but can't find solution.

error looking like this
Notice: Undefined variable : json in **/home/mydomain/public_html/admin/controller/sale/order.php**on line **2491**

Is there any solution for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is written on line 2491? And above?

Comment: $this->response->setOutput($json);

Comment: in mine there is only 2223 lines of code

Comment: Have many issue available in OpenCart 2.0.2.0. So, I think, You need to upgrade your OpenCart version in to latest version. It would be good for the future.

Answer (score 0):

you have to this add code $json = []; after your last function declaration

```
   


    public function api() {
           $json = [];
```

and code have condition when you can get error like you are getting. This issue will be fixed by OC team, you can also search on OC github issues.